# w3-sidebar hamburger toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am implementing the w3-sidebar from:
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar_over

The code uses a "hanburger" to open the side menu and a "Close X" menu item to close it again.

I would like to use the same "hanburger" icon to toggle both the open and close action. So the hanburger is always visible I have added:

```
.w3-sidebar {
  margin-top: 42px;
}
```

The code is:

```js
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
}

function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-border-right" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
      <button onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-large">Close &times;</button>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="w3-teal">
      <button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">☰</button>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <h1>My Page</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <img src="img_car.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">

    <div class="w3-container">
      <p>This sidebar is hidden by default, (style="display:none")</p>
      <p>You must click on the "hamburger" icon (top left) to open it.</p>
      <p>The sidebar will hide a part of the page content.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Change:

```
<button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">☰</button>
```

to

```
<button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_toggle()">☰</button>
```

and add:

```
   function w3_toggle() {
        if (document.getElementById("topMenu").style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById("topMenu").style.display = "block";
        } else { 
            document.getElementById("topMenu").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```